# How to start with U-boot network for PPC in Qemu?

Tags: kernel, qemu, bootloader, u-boot, powerpc

I'm running u-boot for powerpc in Qemu.

```
qemu-system-ppc -M ppce500 -m 512 -kernel u-boot -cpu mpc8572  -nographic -device pcnet,netdev=mynet1 -netdev user,id=mynet1
```

> U-Boot 2020.07-rc4 (Jun 25 2020 - 11:09:31 +0300)

CPU:   8572, Version: 1.0, (0x80e00010)
Core:  e500, Version: 3.0, (0x80210030)
Clock Configuration:
CPU0:  400  MHz,
CCB  : 400  MHz,
DDR:200  MHz (400 MT/s data rate), LBC: unknown (LCRR[CLKDIV] = 0x00   )
L1:     D-cache 32 KiB enabled
I-cache 32 KiB enabled
DRAM:  512 MiB
L2:    disabled

> PCI: base address e0008000

00:01.0     - 1022:2000 - Network controller
PCI1: Bus 00 - 00

In:    serial
Out:    serial
Err:    serial
**Net:   No ethernet found.**
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0

How can I activate the network? or Is it possible to boot the kernel in the hard disk using u-boot?

Answer (score 0):

qemu-ppce500_defconfig has CONFIG_E1000=y.

So something like

```
-device e1000,netdev=eth0 -netdev user,id=eth0
```

gives you the right device on Linux.

But QEMU's hw/ppc/mpc8544_guts.c does not support the registers used.

qemu-ppce500_defconfig has not yet been converted to using CONFIG_DM. I think the way forward would be to convert the board to use the driver model in U-Boot and the virtio network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

As of today the PCI functionality in U-Boot for QEMU ppce500 machine is seriously broken.

The fixes, along with CONFIG_DM conversion, is now in the following series:
http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/uboot/list/?series=230004

We can expect this series to be merged in U-Boot v2021.04 release.